# In my use of button-component with input field, how to set text and button in center of row height and same as input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

I am creating a VueJs3 page with my own custom button template.

My problem is that when using the button together with input field, the button is much higher(aprox 25%) than the input field, though centered on row in height and button text to input field height.

How can I handle this so that input and button has the same hight when on the same row??

[image: Input field and button that is to high]

Below is my code where i use it ( *$t ...* handle translation with i18n )

```
<input v-model="goCell" type="number" size="3" min="1" max="26" v-on:keyup.enter="myExtra(goCell)"/>

<base-button @click="myExtra(goCell)" mode="flat">
   {{$t('Extra meassure')}}
</base-button>
```

And below is my base-button component code.

```
<template>
    <button :class="mode" on-mouseover="message">
    <!-- slot to receive html code-->
    <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['mode', 'message']
}
</script>

<style scoped>
button {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #9d9a9e;
  border: 1px solid #29282b;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  background-color: #a28cb1;
  border-color: #020202;
}

.flat {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #3a0061;
  border: 1px solid #29282b;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(109, 108, 108, 0.26);
  
}

.flat:hover,
.flat:active {
  background-color: #edd2ff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Tried to add image but didn't work ;(

Comment: Fixed. You have lost one ` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In case of Bootstrap use the [Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/)

---

You can try to make input same height as button using the same `padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;`

But I would better suggest you to use some good Frontend-CSS-Framework, like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) or [Bulma](https://bulma.io/).

There are also many good Vue.js ready Design Systems, like [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), [Prime Vue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/) and so on.

You can save you a lot of headache this way.

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue;
const BaseButton = {
    props: ['mode', 'message'],
    template: `
       <button :class="mode" on-mouseover="message">
          <!-- slot to receive html code-->
          <slot></slot>
       </button>`
   }

const App = {
  components: {
    BaseButton
  },
  data() {
    return {
      goCell: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    myExtra() {
      this.goCell++;
    }
  }, 
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
}

input {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #9d9a9e;
  border: 1px solid #29282b;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  background-color: #a28cb1;
  border-color: #020202;
}

.flat {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #3a0061;
  border: 1px solid #29282b;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(109, 108, 108, 0.26);  
}

.flat:hover,
.flat:active {
  background-color: #edd2ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
     <input v-model="goCell" type="number" size="3" min="1" max="26" 
        v-on:keyup.enter="myExtra(goCell)"/>
        
    <base-button @click="myExtra(goCell)" mode="flat">
      click me
    </base-button>
    
    </base-button>    
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"> 
</script>
```

Comment: Using Bootstrap as framework

Comment: You should mention it.

Comment: I have now, thanks to you guys solved my issue. I added styling scooped like this 

````

<style scoped>
input {
  padding: 0.69rem;
}
````

Comment: Sorry Tolbxela, was so focused on my problem and solve it.... My misstake